# Is it possible to detect high impedance at FPGA input?

Tags: vhdl, pullup, pulldown

I am using a FPGA development board which have neither pull-up nor pull-down resister at the input side.

VHDL code that I am developing has to detect either logic zero or logic one and to do respective tasks. But when input is not connected (high impedance state) circuit is behaving abnormally.

Is there is any way by which I can rectify this problem by VHDL programing ?

Comment: What FPGA do you have? Many can do an internal termination which could be used to stop the pin floating. Really you need an external resistor.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Cyclone IV

Comment: The Cyclone IV has programmable pull-up resistors on all input pins.

Comment: To measure impedance, you need current flow. The easiest way to do that is with a pullup or pulldown resistor.

Comment: can you route it to an internal ADC?

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck: Many FPGAs have, but that doesn’t solve the problem for the one being used here.

Comment: Is it a problem to add a pull-up/down resistor?

Comment: First question : why do you want to detect hi-Z? Alternatively, would overriding it with a pullup or pulldown solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the data sheet, https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/cyclone-iv/cyiv-53001.pdf, Table 1-12, Note 1:

> All I/O pins have an option for a weak pullup resistor

So you just need to learn your tools well enough to enable it.